# If statement with multiple || and && not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My `if` statement is not working correctly.

I am pulling in items from a JSON file, trying to show items by brand and show more than one category.

So if the item category is 5 or 6 and the item brand letter is "C" only, I need to show those items. But for some reason with this `if` statement, it's showing other brand letters as well. ex. "B", "F" items are showing as well.

It doesn't seem to be working as it should be. Am I not able to use `||` like I am using it? Because if I remove one of the item category numbers it works but I can't show both categories.

```
          //display peppers function 
          function displayPeppers() {
              var categoryImage = '';
              $.each(product_data, function (i, item) {
                  //convert JSON strings to uppercase for comparison
                  var brandLetter = item.itemBrandLetter.toUpperCase();
                  var foodService = item.itemDeli.toUpperCase();

                  if(item.itemCategory == 5 || item.itemCategory == 6 && brandLetter == "C" && foodService == "N") {
                    categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + 'data-itemcountry="' + item.itemCountry + '"' + 'data-itemcategory="' + item.itemCategory + '"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + item.itemFullUPC + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + item.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + item.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + item.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemlowsodium="' + item.itemLowSodium + '"' + 'data-itemkosher="' + item.itemKosherSym + '"' + 'data-itemorganic="' + item.itemOrganic + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + item.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + item.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + item.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
                  }
              });
              $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');
              closeNav();
          }
```

Comment: Try `if((item.itemCategory == 5 || item.itemCategory == 6) && brandLetter == "C" && foodService == "N") {
 `

Comment: this works thank you! i didnt realize i had to use parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could break for a number of reasons. Mostly having to do with, what exactly does && and || point at?

Is it:

```
if ( 
( item.itemCategory == 5 || item.itemCategory == 6 ) && 
( brandLetter == "C" && foodService == "N" ) ) {}
```

or is it...

```
if ( 
item.itemCategory == 5 || 
( item.itemCategory == 6 && brandLetter == "C" && foodService == "N" ) ) {}
```

And so on.

Use parentheses to clarify what conditions are supposed to resolve.

Comment: thanks i did not realize the importance of using parenthesis with multiple item comparisons. still learning lol. thanks!

Comment: It's easy enough, you'll get it. Just think, if you saw this, "this and that or that or that and this", you could interpret that a whole bunch of ways. "(this and that ) or ( ( that or that ) and this ) ) now makes it clear what's supposed to be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try if `((item.itemCategory == 5 || item.itemCategory == 6) && brandLetter == "C" && foodService == "N") {...`